# CPU-intensive task on iPhones slower in iPads

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, multithreading, core-audio

I'm developing an app for iOS that has a lot of threads and one in particular does a lot of CPU-intensive tasks (advanced math operations,etc.) However in my testing, CPU usage in iPads (tested in iPad 4 and iPad Mini 3) were below 100% (50-70%) while in iPhones (tested in iPhone 5S, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus), CPU usage goes up to 120-140%. The app works well if CPU usage is below 100%.

In particular, the spike in CPU usage for iPhones happens after around 6 seconds of the start of the main task (where all the threads are initiated). What's weird also is that if I press the home button, the app goes to background and CPU usage drops to the preferred value. Even if I put the app back to the foreground, the CPU usage levels stay the same, thus the app works well.

What I want to know is (1) what causes the spike in CPU usage in iPhones (and why it does not happen in iPads), and (2) if there is a way to avoid that spike (seeing that CPU usage can dropped by moving the app to the background).

Side notes: 
 1. The app uses the Core Audio framework.
 2. Right now, I'm using pthreads. I've also tried using GCD and the priority values (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND and DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW) but it lowers the CPU usage too much that the thread can't perform much. 
3. There's a lot of C/C++ code on the back-end of the app.

Any help will be appreciated. ^_^

Comment: Use the time profiler instrument to analyse your app.  It is impossible for to say what is causing your apps behaviour without seeing it

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for the reply. :) Yes, I've used the Time Profiler Instrument but it only shows that the math thread is the one who uses the CPU the most, but that's the result in either the iPad or the iPhone.

Comment: One possibility is that the iPad's have bigger heat sinks on the A7/A8 chips, and don't throttle the CPU clock speed as soon to prevent exceeding some temperature range.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Thank you for the reply :) Hmmm...I see, that explanation is consistent here. [link] (http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/ipad-airs-a7-chip-is-identical-to-the-iphones-just-faster/) But does that mean that pressing the home button removes the throttling? Is there a way to stop the throttling in the first place?

Comment: Stop throttling?  Maybe an icepack on the back of the iPhone?  Putting an iOS app in the background may reconfigure Audio Units callbacks to use larger buffers, thus less frequent activity.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I see, that seems to be the case..I've tried a larger buffer for the Audio Unit and the iPhone 6 Plus took a few normal runs before spiking again. Probably because it has a bigger heat sink than the iPhone 6. Thanks again!